# How to render Views or Partial Views of scripts at the bottom in _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, scriptbundle

I have a problem in rendering few of my partial view’s script tags should render at the bottom in _Layout.cshtml page.

Comment: Scripts should not be in partial views.

Comment: What Helper do you use?

Comment: I am using `@Scripts.Render("path of the file")`

Answer (score 0):

I got solution,You may not want to render everything on every page. Sectioning gives you control of that.

In `_Layout .cshtml` define scripts tags like this,

```
<script src="/scripts/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
@if (IsSectionDefined("bottomScripts"))
{
    @RenderSection("bottomScripts", required: false) 
}
```

In `YourView.cshtml` define a section like this

```
@section bottomScripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

Here is a standard structure of Layout and Views in MVC.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset=" utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/css/stye1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/css/style2.css" />
    @if (IsSectionDefined("myStyles"))
    { 
       @RenderSection("myStyles", required: false);
    }
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <a href="/Index">
        <h1>My Website<small>Your Slogan</small></h1>
    </a>
</header>
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/script1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/script2.js"></script>
@if (IsSectionDefined("myScripts"))
{
    @RenderSection("myScripts", required: false);
}
</body>
</html>
```

**View1.cshtml**

```
<div>This is View1</div>
@section myStyles{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Pagespecificstyle.css" />
}
@section myScripts{
<script src="~/PageSpecificScript.js"></script>
}
```

**View2.cshtml**

```
<div>This is View2</div>
@section myStyles{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Pagespecificstyle2.css" />
}
@section myScripts{
<script src="~/PageSpecificScript2.js"></script>
}
```